# Problems with chemical molecules in subfigures

Tags: subfloats, alignment, chemfig, chemistry

I am trying to arrange a `subfigure` like 1 big on the left, one in the upper right and 4 left below. The figures are framed with a custom `tcolorbox`.

All of my subfigures worked so far but for some reasons, this one does not work as expected.

This is my result so far:
[image]

For my MWE I deleted the big molecules to make the code more readable (I just left Uracil so you can see nothing is centered an in its place).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=quad}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=white,colframe=black,arc=5mm, halign=center}

\begin{document}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases
\definesubmol{Abase}{(([:36]\chembelow{N}{H}*5(-(*6(-N=-N=(-NH_2)-=))--N=-)))}
\definesubmol{Gbase}{(([:36]\chembelow{N}{H}*5(-(*6(-N=(-NH_2)-NH-(=O)-=))--N=-)))}
\definesubmol{Cbase}{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-N=(-NH_2)-=)}
\definesubmol{Ubase}{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-NH-(=O)-=)}
\definesubmol{a}{-P(=[::90,0.75]O)(-[::-90,0.75]OH)-}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% sugar-backbone

\definesubmol{backB}{[:-54]*5((-[:90]-[:180]O([:180]!a\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O}))<(-HO)-[,,,,line width=2pt](-OH)>(-R)-O-)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% sugar-backbone

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases for RNA assembly

\definesubmol{ARbase}{((-[:90]N*5(-(*6(-N=-N=(-NH_2)-=))--N=-)))}

\definesubmol{GRbase}{((-[:90]N*5(-(*6(-N=(-NH_2)-[,,,1]NH-[,,1](=O)-=))--N=-)))}

\definesubmol{CRbase}{-[:90]N*6(-(=O)-N=(-NH_2)-=-)}

\definesubmol{URbase}{-[:90]N*6(-(=O)-NH=(=O)-=-)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases for RNA assembly

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RNA nucleotide assembly

\definesubmol{4th}{-[:180]O-[:180]X(=[:-90]O)(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})-[:90]O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{CRbase})-O-(-[:90]-[:180]O-[:180]P(-[:90]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(=[:-90]O))<))}   % upper end segment

\definesubmol{3rd}{-[:180]O-[:180]P(=[:-90]O)(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})-[:90]O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{GRbase})-O-(-[:90]!{4th})<))} % third middle segment

\definesubmol{2nd}{O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{ARbase})-O-(-[:90]!{3rd})<))} % second middle segment

\definesubmol{RNA}{[:-54]*5((-[:90]-[:180]O([:180]-P(-\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(=[:-90]O)(-[::-90]!{2nd})))<(-[:-90]HO)-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{URbase})-O-)} % bottom end segment

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RNA nucleotide assembly


\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{mybox}
            \scalebox{0.45}{
            \chemfig{!{RNA}}
            \chemmove{%
                \node[at=(cyclecenter4),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=48](){};
            }
            \chemmove{%
                \node[at=(cyclecenter3),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=180](){};
            }   
            \chemmove{%
                \node[at=(cyclecenter10),fill=yellow,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
            }       
            \chemmove{%
                \node[at=(cyclecenter9),fill=green,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
            }   
            \chemmove{%
                \node[at=(cyclecenter7),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=48](){};
            }
            \chemmove{%
                \node[at=(cyclecenter6),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=180](){};
            }   
        }
    \end{mybox}
        \caption[RNA]{RNA chain}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.37\textwidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox} 
            \scalebox{0.6}{\chemfig{!{backB}}}
        \end{mybox}
            \caption{sugar backbone}
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.30}{\chemfig{[:72]!{Abase}}
                    \chemmove{%
                        \node[at=(cyclecenter2),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                    }
                    \chemmove{%
                        \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=90](){};
                }}
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{adenine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.30}{\chemfig{[:72]!{Gbase}}
                    \chemmove{%
                        \node[at=(cyclecenter2),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                    }
                    \chemmove{%
                        \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=90](){};
                }   }
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{guanine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.30}{\chemfig{!{Cbase}}
                    \chemmove{%
                        \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=green,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                }}
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{cytosine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
            \scalebox{0.30}{
                %\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
                %\schemestart
            \chemfig{!{Ubase}}
            \chemmove{%
                \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=yellow,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
            }
                %\schemestop
            }
        \end{mybox}
            \caption{uracil}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \par\bigskip
    \decoRule
    \caption{RNA structural organisation: \lipsum[1]}\label{reduced}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Entirely unrelated the the alignment issue itself, but I'd avoid using different scale factors for the indvidual parts of the image. This results in inconsitent font sizes and line widths inside of the same figure and makes it look a little cluttered/busy, especially in combination with the comparably thick/bold lines of the boxes. If you have to scale down formulae, I'd use the same factor for all of them, probably also paired with a smaller bond length (e.g. `\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}` or something similar.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should result in an output closer to the expected one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=quad}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=white,colframe=black,arc=5mm, halign=center}

\begin{document}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases
\definesubmol{Ubase}{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-NH-(=O)-=)}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases



\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{mybox}
            \scalebox{0.45}{
            \chemfig[scale=0.45]{!{Ubase}}
        }
    \end{mybox}
        \caption[RNA]{RNA chain}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.37\textwidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox} 
            \scalebox{0.6}{\chemfig{!{Ubase}}}
        \end{mybox}
            \caption{sugar backbone}
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.30}{\chemfig{!{Ubase}}}
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{adenine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.30}{\chemfig{!{Ubase}}}
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{guanine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.30}{\chemfig{!{Ubase}}}
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{cytosine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
            \scalebox{0.30}{
                \setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
                \schemestart
            \chemfig{!{Ubase}}
            \chemmove{%
                \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=yellow,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
            }
                \schemestop
            }
        \end{mybox}
            \caption{uracil}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \par\bigskip
    \decoRule
    \caption{RNA structural organisation: \lipsum[1]}\label{reduced}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Applied to the entire image, this is the output and corresponding MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=quad}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=white,colframe=black,arc=5mm, halign=center}


    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases
\definesubmol{Abase}{(([:36]\chembelow{N}{H}*5(-(*6(-N=-N=(-NH_2)-=))--N=-)))}
\definesubmol{Gbase}{(([:36]\chembelow{N}{H}*5(-(*6(-N=(-NH_2)-NH-(=O)-=))--N=-)))}
\definesubmol{Cbase}{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-N=(-NH_2)-=)}
\definesubmol{Ubase}{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-NH-(=O)-=)}
\definesubmol{a}{-P(=[::90,0.75]O)(-[::-90,0.75]OH)-}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% sugar-backbone

\definesubmol{backB}{[:-54]*5((-[:90]-[:180]O([:180]!a\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O}))<(-HO)-[,,,,line width=2pt](-OH)>(-R)-O-)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% sugar-backbone

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases for RNA assembly

\definesubmol{ARbase}{((-[:90]N*5(-(*6(-N=-N=(-NH_2)-=))--N=-)))}
                  
\definesubmol{GRbase}{((-[:90]N*5(-(*6(-N=(-NH_2)-[,,,1]NH-[,,1](=O)-=))--N=-)))}

\definesubmol{CRbase}{-[:90]N*6(-(=O)-N=(-NH_2)-=-)}

\definesubmol{URbase}{-[:90]N*6(-(=O)-NH=(=O)-=-)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases for RNA assembly

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RNA nucleotide assembly

\definesubmol{4th}{-[:180]O-[:180]X(=[:-90]O)(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})-[:90]O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{CRbase})-O-(-[:90]-[:180]O-[:180]P(-[:90]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(=[:-90]O))<))}   % upper end segment

\definesubmol{3rd}{-[:180]O-[:180]P(=[:-90]O)(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})-[:90]O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{GRbase})-O-(-[:90]!{4th})<))} % third middle segment

\definesubmol{2nd}{O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{ARbase})-O-(-[:90]!{3rd})<))} % second middle segment

\definesubmol{RNA}{[:-54]*5((-[:90]-[:180]O([:180]-P(-\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(=[:-90]O)(-[::-90]!{2nd})))<(-[:-90]HO)-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{URbase})-O-)} % bottom end segment

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RNA nucleotide assembly

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{mybox}
            \scalebox{0.45}{
              \chemfig{!{RNA}}
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter4),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=48](){};
              }
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter3),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=180](){};
              }   
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter10),fill=yellow,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
              }       
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter9),fill=green,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
              }   
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter7),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=48](){};
              }
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter6),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=180](){};
              }   
            }
        \end{mybox}
        \caption[RNA]{RNA chain}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.37\textwidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox} 
            \scalebox{0.6}{
              \chemfig{!{backB}}
            }
        \end{mybox}
            \caption{sugar backbone}
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.30}{
                  \chemfig{[:72]!{Abase}}
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter2),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                }
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{adenine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.30}{
                  \chemfig{[:72]!{Gbase}}
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter2),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=90](){};
                  }  
                }
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{guanine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.30}{
                  \chemfig{!{Cbase}}
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=green,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                }
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{cytosine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
            \scalebox{0.30}{
              \chemfig{!{Ubase}}
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=yellow,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
              }
            }
        \end{mybox}
            \caption{uracil}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \par\bigskip
    \decoRule
    \caption{RNA structural organisation: \lipsum[1]}\label{reduced}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is an alternative that uses a lighter and thinner border around the individual subfigures, as well as even scale factors for all molecules for a less busy look:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=quad}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=white,colframe=gray!50!white,arc=5mm, halign=center, boxrule=1pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=7.25pt, bottom=7.25pt}


    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases
\definesubmol{Abase}{(([:36]\chembelow{N}{H}*5(-(*6(-N=-N=(-NH_2)-=))--N=-)))}
\definesubmol{Gbase}{(([:36]\chembelow{N}{H}*5(-(*6(-N=(-NH_2)-NH-(=O)-=))--N=-)))}
\definesubmol{Cbase}{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-N=(-NH_2)-=)}
\definesubmol{Ubase}{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-NH-(=O)-=)}
\definesubmol{a}{-P(=[::90,0.75]O)(-[::-90,0.75]OH)-}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% sugar-backbone

\definesubmol{backB}{[:-54]*5((-[:90]-[:180]O([:180]!a\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O}))<(-HO)-[,,,,line width=2pt](-OH)>(-R)-O-)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% sugar-backbone

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases for RNA assembly

\definesubmol{ARbase}{((-[:90]N*5(-(*6(-N=-N=(-NH_2)-=))--N=-)))}
                  
\definesubmol{GRbase}{((-[:90]N*5(-(*6(-N=(-NH_2)-[,,,1]NH-[,,1](=O)-=))--N=-)))}

\definesubmol{CRbase}{-[:90]N*6(-(=O)-N=(-NH_2)-=-)}

\definesubmol{URbase}{-[:90]N*6(-(=O)-NH=(=O)-=-)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases for RNA assembly

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RNA nucleotide assembly

\definesubmol{4th}{-[:180]O-[:180]X(=[:-90]O)(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})-[:90]O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{CRbase})-O-(-[:90]-[:180]O-[:180]P(-[:90]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(=[:-90]O))<))}   % upper end segment

\definesubmol{3rd}{-[:180]O-[:180]P(=[:-90]O)(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})-[:90]O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{GRbase})-O-(-[:90]!{4th})<))} % third middle segment

\definesubmol{2nd}{O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{ARbase})-O-(-[:90]!{3rd})<))} % second middle segment

\definesubmol{RNA}{[:-54]*5((-[:90]-[:180]O([:180]-P(-\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(=[:-90]O)(-[::-90]!{2nd})))<(-[:-90]HO)-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{URbase})-O-)} % bottom end segment

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RNA nucleotide assembly

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.525\textwidth}
        \begin{mybox}
            \scalebox{0.5}{
              \chemfig{!{RNA}}
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter4),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=48](){};
              }
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter3),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=180](){};
              }   
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter10),fill=yellow,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
              }       
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter9),fill=green,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
              }   
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter7),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=48](){};
              }
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter6),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=180](){};
              }   
            }
        \end{mybox}
        \caption[RNA]{RNA chain}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox} 
            \scalebox{0.5}{
              \chemfig{!{backB}}
            }
        \end{mybox}
            \caption{sugar backbone}
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.5}{
                  \chemfig{[:72]!{Abase}}
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter2),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                }
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{adenine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.5}{
                  \chemfig{[:72]!{Gbase}}
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter2),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=13.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=90](){};
                  }  
                }
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{guanine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.5}{
                  \chemfig{!{Cbase}}
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=green,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                }
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{cytosine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.475\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
            \scalebox{0.5}{
              \chemfig{!{Ubase}}
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=yellow,opacity=0.2,inner sep=17.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
              }
            }
        \end{mybox}
            \caption{uracil}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \par\bigskip
    \decoRule
    \caption{RNA structural organisation: \lipsum[1]}\label{reduced}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is a version with shorter bond lengths. As you can see, the font size of the atoms is now just a little bit smaller than the font size of the captions. This is especially visible if comparing this with the first two images i which the font sizes of the molecules are almost illegibly tiny if compared to the font sizes of the captions. I also rearranged the nucleo bases in subfigure C to F in order to show a wider and a narrower base side by side.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=quad}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=white,colframe=gray!50!white,arc=5mm, halign=center, boxrule=1pt}


    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases
\definesubmol{Abase}{(([:36]\chembelow{N}{H}*5(-(*6(-N=-N=(-NH_2)-=))--N=-)))}
\definesubmol{Gbase}{(([:36]\chembelow{N}{H}*5(-(*6(-N=(-NH_2)-NH-(=O)-=))--N=-)))}
\definesubmol{Cbase}{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-N=(-NH_2)-=)}
\definesubmol{Ubase}{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)-NH-(=O)-=)}
\definesubmol{a}{-P(=[::90,0.75]O)(-[::-90,0.75]OH)-}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% sugar-backbone

\definesubmol{backB}{[:-54]*5((-[:90]-[:180]O([:180]!a\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O}))<(-HO)-[,,,,line width=2pt](-OH)>(-R)-O-)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% sugar-backbone

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases for RNA assembly

\definesubmol{ARbase}{((-[:90]N*5(-(*6(-N=-N=(-NH_2)-=))--N=-)))}
                  
\definesubmol{GRbase}{((-[:90]N*5(-(*6(-N=(-NH_2)-[,,,1]NH-[,,1](=O)-=))--N=-)))}

\definesubmol{CRbase}{-[:90]N*6(-(=O)-N=(-NH_2)-=-)}

\definesubmol{URbase}{-[:90]N*6(-(=O)-NH=(=O)-=-)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% nucleobases for RNA assembly

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RNA nucleotide assembly

\definesubmol{4th}{-[:180]O-[:180]X(=[:-90]O)(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})-[:90]O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{CRbase})-O-(-[:90]-[:180]O-[:180]P(-[:90]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(=[:-90]O))<))}   % upper end segment

\definesubmol{3rd}{-[:180]O-[:180]P(=[:-90]O)(-[:180]\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})-[:90]O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{GRbase})-O-(-[:90]!{4th})<))} % third middle segment

\definesubmol{2nd}{O-[:90]([:54]*5(-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{ARbase})-O-(-[:90]!{3rd})<))} % second middle segment

\definesubmol{RNA}{[:-54]*5((-[:90]-[:180]O([:180]-P(-\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})(=[:-90]O)(-[::-90]!{2nd})))<(-[:-90]HO)-[,,,,line width=4pt](-[:-90]OH)>(!{URbase})-O-)} % bottom end segment

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RNA nucleotide assembly

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.525\textwidth}
        \begin{mybox}
            \scalebox{0.725}{
              \chemfig{!{RNA}}
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter4),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=12.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=48](){};
              }
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter3),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=9.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=180](){};
              }   
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter10),fill=yellow,opacity=0.2,inner sep=12.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
              }       
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter9),fill=green,opacity=0.2,inner sep=12.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
              }   
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter7),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=12.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=48](){};
              }
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter6),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=9.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=180](){};
              }   
            }
        \end{mybox}
        \caption[RNA]{RNA chain}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox} 
            \scalebox{0.725}{
              \chemfig{!{backB}}
            }
        \end{mybox}
            \caption{sugar backbone}
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.55\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.725}{
                  \chemfig{[:72]!{Abase}}
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter2),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=12.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=red,opacity=0.2,inner sep=9.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                }
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{adenine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
            \scalebox{0.725}{
              \chemfig{!{Ubase}}
              \chemmove{%
                  \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=yellow,opacity=0.2,inner sep=12.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
              }
            }
        \end{mybox}
            \caption{uracil}
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\bigskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.55\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.725}{
                  \chemfig{[:72]!{Gbase}}
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter2),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=12.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=cyan,opacity=0.2,inner sep=9.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,rotate=90](){};
                  }  
                }
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{guanine}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
            \begin{mybox}
                \scalebox{0.725}{
                  \chemfig{!{Cbase}}
                  \chemmove{%
                      \node[at=(cyclecenter1),fill=green,opacity=0.2,inner sep=12.5pt,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,rotate=90](){};
                  }
                }
            \end{mybox}
            \caption{cytosine}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \par\bigskip
    \decoRule
    \caption{RNA structural organisation: \lipsum[1]}\label{reduced}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I reassembled my molecules the problem accours again. See my Edit.

Comment: Since the code for the entire molecule is sadly not available, I can't reproduce the output you show in your updated question. Using just the code for the sugar backbone, I get the exact same alignment as the one in my answer, thus I currently can't tell what went wrong. https://i.stack.imgur.com/81ebN.png

Comment: I added the full code

Comment: @Roland: Isn't that still the original, non adapted version? The full code you added still uses the `\parbox` approach, which I replaced with a `minipage` in my answer. Also, the `\centering` commands inside of the `\scalebox` commands, which I remove, are still there.

Comment: If I take the MWE from my answer and just replace the molecules with the ones you added to your question in your recent edit, I end up with the following output https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSImb.png that is significantly different from the one you showed and should also show the expected alignment.

Comment: Yes, you are right sorry. I added the other version.

Comment: Yes that is also what I get (slightly different)

Comment: @Roland: I've just updated my answer accordingly and also added an alternativer version, that also addresses the [issues mentioned in my previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606608/problems-with-chemical-molecules-in-subfigures/606612?noredirect=1#comment1520797_606608).

Comment: Thank you very much. The reduced font sized looks indeed more appealing.